# Prove by mathematical induction: $n < 2^n$

Tags: inequality, induction

Step 1: prove for 
$n = 1$

1 < 2

Step 2:

$n+1 < 2 \cdot 2^n$

$n < 2 \cdot 2^n - 1$

$n < 2^n + 2^n - 1$

The function $2^n + 2^n - 1$ is surely higher than $2^n - 1$ so if

$n < 2^n$ is true (induction step), $n < 2^n + 2^n - 1$ has to be true as well.

Is this valid argumentation?

Comment: This question is similar: [Prove by mathematical induction that $2n ≤ 2^n$, for all integer $n≥1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169859/prove-by-mathematical-induction-that-2n-2n-for-all-integer-n1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Your method works. Alternate: $$ n + 1 < 2n < 2 \cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}, $$ as desired.

Comment: You state that n+1<2n. But this isn't true for n=0. What am I missing?

Comment: This proves the results for all $ n > 0 $.

Answer (score 7):

$$n+1<n+n<2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}$$

Comment: Beaten by 35 seconds!

Comment: @AhaanRungta :-)

Comment: Thank you. I'll give the answer to @AhaanRungta though, because he answered the question.

Comment: Thanks! Bateman beat me to it, so I'll give him an upvote. :) Also, Grant, you didn't give me the check mark (accepted answer). :P

Comment: @Grant: bateman answered the question in the title, which should be arguably more important than anything you ask in the text (unless explictly said otherwise).

Comment: @Marek Very true. I suggest not making a big distinction between our posts, Grant. ;)

Comment: @Ahaan: it would be nice to be able to mark multiple answers as correct because this can definitely happen. But that's discussion for another time and place I suppose :)

Comment: Yes, more likely the Meta section. :P

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that $k+1 < 2^{k+1}$, from the original equation, replacing $n$ with $k$:
$$k + 1 < 2^k + 1$$
Thus, one needs to show that:
$$2^k + 1 < 2^{k + 1}$$
to complete the proof.

We know that $1 < 2^k$ for $k ≥ 1$. Adding $2^k$ to both sides:
$$2^k + 1 < 2^k + 2^k = 2^{k+1},$$
which shows that
$n < 2^n$.